# Temporarily use a Samsung A40 screen with a Samsung A30

Tags: screen, hardware

A friend of mine broke her screen (samsung A40), and she would like to recover her photos (not saved on google photo, debug mode not enabled). We struggle to unlock the screen blindly, so I was thinking of using the screen of another phone (samsung A30) to temporarily replace the screen just the time to get the picture.

Is there a chance for this procedure to work? How can I check if both screens are compatible?

Comment: Usually for replacing you need identical components because the display and digitizer drivers are integrated into your system's kernel and can not be replaced and usually they only support one specific component.

Comment: @Robert you mean this device tree thing? Arggg. So there is no solution?

Comment: I am not an expert to Samsung A30/A40 display. Based on the hardware specs they have the same resolution but different screen size. But besides this data I don't know anything, e.g. if the hardware connector is identical and what digitizer is used. Also keep in mind that when switching display you may end up with two defect displays...

Comment: It is unlikely that it would work, and you could damage some electronics.